# Preallocating a large array in a MATLAB matfile with something other than zeroes

Tags: arrays, matlab, large-data

I need to write an array that is too large to fit into memory to a .mat binary file. This can be accomplished with the [`matfile`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) command, which allows random access to a .mat file on disc.

I am trying to preallocate the array in this file, and the approach recommended by a [MathWorks blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/10/14/new-mat-file-functionality-in-r2011b/#17) is

```
matObj = matfile('myBigData.mat','Writable',true); 
matObj.X(10000,10000) = 0;
```

This works, but leaves me with a large array of zeroes - which is risky, as some of the genuine values that I will be populating it with may also be zero. For smaller arrays, I would typically do

```
smallarray = nan(20,20);
```

But if I try this approach for the large array I get an "out of memory" error; presumably the `nan()` function is producing the large array of `NaN`s in memory first.

**How can I preallocate a large array with something other than zeroes?**

Comment: Hmm, related question I suppose is whether there's any *need* to preallocate in this case. The usual performance benefit will presumably be trivial compared to the time taken to write stuff to disc... guess it avoids the file being fragmented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that neither sclarke81's nor Sam Robert's answers actually work, and I doubt that the concept of preallocation applies to `matfile`. Results reported below were obtained on an i7-3770 CPU @ 3.4 GHz with 16.8 GB of main memory, running Matlab R2013a on Linux 3.16.

The code

```
mf = matfile(fn, 'Writable', true);
mf.x(5000, 200000) = 0;
clear mf
```

theoretically "allocates" 8 GB of memory on disk, initialized to 0. However, the resulting file has a size of 4726 bytes and the process takes less than 0.01 seconds. I can increase the size 10- or 100-fold, and nothing much changes. Strange. Btw., the `clear` at the end is there to ensure that the file is written and closed by Matlab.

Often we want to preallocate initializing to NaN instead of 0. Doing this the *received* way

```
mf = matfile(fn, 'Writable', true);
mf.x = nan(5000, 200000);
clear mf
```

takes 11 seconds and results in a file of 57 MB. But as the OP pointed out, this approach doesn't make sense because it first generates the whole matrix of 8 GB in memory and then writes it out, which defeats the purpose of `matfile`. If the matrix fits into memory, there's no reason in the first place to keep the data in a file while processing it.

Sam Roberts proposed to first allocate/initialize to 0 as above, and then change the values to NaN:

```
mf = matfile(fn, 'Writable', true);
mf.x(5000, 200000) = 0;
mf.x = mf.x * nan;
clear mf
```

This takes 16 seconds, with the same resulting file size. However, this in no way better than the naive approach above, because on the third line the whole matrix is read into memory, multiplied with scalar NaN in-memory, and then written out again, leading to a peak memory consumption of 8 GB. (This is not only consistent with the semantics of `matfile`-variables explained in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html), but I also checked with a memory usage monitor.)

sclarke81 proposed to instead avoid generation of the matrix in memory this way:

```
mf = matfile(fn, 'Writable', true);
mf.x(1 : 5000, 1 : 200000) = nan;
clear mf
```

the idea probably being that only a scalar NaN is generated in memory, and then copied into every element of the on-disk matrix. However, that's not what happens. As a matter of fact, this method appears to consume about 8.38 GB of memory at peak, 12 % more than the naive approach!

Now more on the merits of preallocation with `matfile`. If one does not preallocate, but fills the array row-wise with NaNs

```
mf = matfile(fn, 'Writable', true);
for i = 1 : 5000
    mf.x(i, 1 : 200000) = nan(1, 200000);
end
clear mf
```

this takes 27 seconds. *But*, if one preallocates initializing to 0 and then row-wise overwrites by NaNs

```
mf = matfile(fn, 'Writable', true);
mf.x(5000, 200000) = 0;
for i = 1 : 5000
    mf.x(i, 1 : 200000) = nan(1, 200000);
end
clear mf
```

it takes ages: the process was only about 3% finished when I aborted it after 45 minutes, extrapolating to about *a day* of total runtime!

The behavior of `matlab.io.MatFile` is dark and mysterious, and it seems that at the moment, only testing extensively will lead to an effective way to use this facility. However, one may conclude that preallocation is a bad idea when it comes to `matfile`.

Comment: @A Donda: Appreciate your quantitative results for the identified approaches. MATLAB/RAM/OS limits are known, but the HDD.IO is the killer. Spending days just on preallocation of `NaN`s is nothing but a luxurious waste of resources. As presented in >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/27083554/3666197 the `matfile`/HDF5 and the real BigDATA problems require a way more carefull data manipulation strategies, than a *preallocation*. [n.b. HDF5 format's strength is in it's support for efficient implementation of dynamic changes of the data elements in the BigDATA scales, not for the *static* content]

Comment: Very interesting! Regarding your last finding... I wonder if conversion from 1 (an int) to nan (a float) could be partially responsible for the slowdown. I don't currently have a MATLAB install so can't check this myself. Could you repeat the last experiment but initialise `mf.x` to nan (or a float like 0.1)?

Comment: ... I'm just trying to fact-check that NaN is a float in MATLAB. Apologies if this is incorrect. Getting too used to Python/Numpy!

Comment: @GnomeDePlume, numbers in Matlab are all 8-byte floats ("doubles") by default, getting anything else needs special effort. NaNs aren't even defined in anything but floating-point number formats afaik. There's also no conversion, `nan(1, 200000)` means "give me an array of size 1 x 200000 initialized with NaNs.

Comment: I suspect the slowdown comes from the fact that the mat-file is heavily compressed, and changing anything means reading, decompressing, updating the contents, compressing, writing. I tried to find a way to disable compression, but haven't found anything. I suspect using `memmapfile` instead of `matfile` is more useful for the OP's purposes (as well as mine).

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me. Note that you have to specify the range for the matrix index (`X(1:10000,1:10000)`), otherwise you just set the single element at `10000,10000` to `NaN`.

```
matObj = matfile('myBigData.mat','Writable',true); 
matObj.X(1:10000,1:10000) = NaN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like:

```
matObj = matfile('myBigData.mat','Writable',true); 
matObj.X(10000,10000) = 0;
```

and then

```
matObj.X = matObj.X + 1;
```

or

```
matObj.X = matObj.X * NaN;
```

?

Comment: That's a good thought, and it works. I'm going to accept the other answer because it involves fewer steps, but thank you.

Comment: I agree - the other answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

This can be performed by memory-mapping a binary file, using [`MappedTensor`](http://dylan-muir.com/articles/mapped_tensor/) (self-citation).

```
% - Create and map a large 'double' tensor to a temporary file on disk
mt = MappedTensor(100, 100, 100);

% - % Write 'nan' to every element of 'mt', without allocating entire tensor
mt(:) = nan;
```

You can try a similar approach with `memmapfile`, but `memmapfile` allocates space for the entire tensor when writing to a mapped file.

You can preallocate and then map a specific binary file using `fsutil` on a PC, or `fallocate` on a mac or linux machine.