# When writing a large array directly to disk in MATLAB, is there any need to preallocate?

Tags: matlab, performance, file-io, dynamic-arrays, large-data

I need to write an array that is too large to fit into memory to a .mat binary file. This can be accomplished with the [`matfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) function, which allows random access to a .mat file on disk.

Normally, the accepted advice is to preallocate arrays, because expanding them on every iteration of a loop is slow. However, when I was [asking how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139832/preallocating-a-large-array-in-a-matlab-matfile-with-something-other-than-zeroes), it occurred to me that this may not be good advice when writing to disk rather than RAM.

**Will the same performance hit from *growing* the array apply**, and **if** so, will it be ***significant*** when **compared to the time it takes to write to disk** anyway?

(Assume that the whole file will be written in *one session*, so the risk of serious file fragmentation is ***low***.)

Comment: I am just curious on why would you go for this design rather than splitting the file into many. You are already block processing due to RAM constraints in Matlab, so you could as well extend this logic to the storage task.

Comment: @OlegKomarov the background is that I'm retrieving time series for lots of points from a .NET interface. I eventually need to process it on a all-timesteps-for-a-given-point basis, but the .NET interface only allows me to retrieve it on a all-points-for-a-given-timestep basis. Simplest way seemed to be to put it all in a huge array a row at a time, and then read it back a column at a time.

Comment: I suspect that looping the timestep (from the .NET interface) for a given point might be faster than retrieving in bulk + saving on disc + reading it back + writing the whole code to handle the block processing (especially this last point is very time consuming and prone errors).

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with .mat files? [Memory mapped files](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/import_export/overview-of-memory-mapping.html) are there just for such cases.

Comment: @OlegKomarov hmm, fair point...

Comment: @bdecaf I'm not sure what the additional benefit would be. mmapfile gives random access to an arbitrary binary file on disc (but then it's up to the user to manage data structures). matfile gives random access specifically to a Matlab binary on disc, letting matlab worry about data structures.

Comment: @SimonW  would you, please, add a few **quantitative details important for performance envelope(s)**, that would allow to critically assess available workaround(s) altogether with the (un)-avoid-able overheads associated with 'em? **[a]** How big is your "large" **`array`** in `[TB]`. **[b]** How much `static` / how much varying is the array / sparse-array / size/shape/mapping during the phase of further processing? **[c]** How intensive is your processing-phase's **number-crunching** expected / estimated to be -- in `[GFLOPs * hrs]`

Comment: There are issues with random access or not pre-allocating when using `matfile`.  Performance is an issue, but oddly so is disk utilization.  Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19578346/2778484).  Writing in pre-allocated blocks (just blocks since final size wasn't known) was an effective workaround to a bad bug.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I think there is some confusion that needs to be cleared. There is no indication that `matfile` will write the file in a contiguous block on the disk nor there are low level `.m` routines that allow to control the behaviour of `save()`. In simple words, within Matlab, it makes no sense to talk about preallocating a file on disk.

Comment: @horchler well that was a pretty pointless set of edits! I've reverted the only one that was actually wrong (MATLAB should be capitalised, according to the vendor's style guide), and for the disc/disk thing merely looked up http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8474/is-there-a-difference-between-disc-and-disk-for-naming-digital-storage-media and chuckled ;-)

Comment: @user3666197 It was a while ago, so I don't have things easily to hand. However, the large array was in the order of hundreds of Gb. It would be fully, or nearly fully, populated (ie not sparse), but would not change substantially (if at all - in fact, a map/reduce approach might have been better). I have no idea how to calculate the number of FPOs involved, but initially at least it was just a matter of calculating the means and maxes of columns (hence my comment about map/reduce). However, is all this detail relevant to the general question?

Comment: @chappjc Youch! Worth knowing, thank you. Might be worth writing that as an answer, so that it lasts for people reading this in the future?

Comment: **Oh yes, it is very important**. While pre-allocation is a static issue & happens just once, WRITE-through & READ IO-s (the more once given to be *sort of* random) are much more important as being intensive+random. **The whole science & art of HPC is about data-access/data-xfer into-CPU-cache performance** ( not the in-CPU computation, not the static storage layout(s), be it in-RAM or on-Disk, the CPU-s are so fast & so powerfull today, that in-CPU-cache load-in data from RAM / load-off results to RAM is by several orders of magnitude slower bottleneck. Scale-up & understand disk-IO issues )

Comment: **[c]** is also important,in both of it's dimensions.It addresses both the scale of the computation(simplified as the amount of FLOP/IOP-s needed to get the result,i.e. to AVG a column of 100.000 Floats, 100 kFLOP-s on .ADD + 1 FLOP on .DIV,if known,static,size of the column, or additionaly some 100 kIOP-s on .INC to get a divisor for .DIV) & the **time-span/repetitiveness of the processing** (how many hours you estimate the circus to run,before your goal is achieved - Be it just once, or being that needed to start that same volume of FLOP/IOP-s each 5 mins for the next year). **Both matter.**

Comment: Thanks for your comment on the nature of random IO + column-wise `mean()`/`max()`-es. Having that said, the computational density over the given dataSet is indeed a very low one and you can assume the problem to be rather inefficient to be "en-graved" into a monolythic file just for this type of calculation. **`1E6`** `double` Float-values * **`1E5`** columns yield about **`0.8 TB`** ( sure, excl. file-format overheads ) makes space ( in case no other math is behind the corner ( sumproduct(s), convolution(s) et al ) for much smarter and way faster pipe-line-d processing, than a file-based one.

Comment: @OlegKomarov It certainly *should* make no sense, but unfortunately given issues with `matfile`, there is a difference.  See [the question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578346/excessively-large-overhead-in-matlab-mat-file) that I liked to above.  There was a massive difference in final file size depending on whether you take certain steps to pre-allocate the arrays you plan to write rather than expanding them.  Now, it's not to be expected that the file will be in contiguous blocks, but it should certainly not be so sparse and/or packed full of junk.

Comment: @SimonW I'm not eager to copy my answer, but if I get a minute I'll copy the gist of it.

Comment: @chappjc ah, sorry, I didn't mean copy your other answer - I meant link to it as an answer here, with a little explanation, since comments are more ephemeral? I'm not sure what SO policy is on answers that are links to other answers, though!

Comment: Hmm. This question seems to be suffering feature creep ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Q: Will the same performance hit from growing the array apply, and if so will it be significant when compared to the time it takes to write to disk anyway?**

A: Yes, performance will suffer if you significantly grow a file on disk without pre-allocating. The performance hit will be a consequence of fragmentation. As you mentioned, fragmentation is less of a risk if the file is written in one session, but will cause problems if the file grows significantly.

A [related question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/22350-big-problem-bug-with-new-matfile-command-for-partial-mat-file-read-writes-creates-massivly-bloated) was raised on the MathWorks website, and the accepted answer was to pre-allocate when possible.

If you don't pre-allocate, then the extent of your performance problems will depend on:

- your filesystem (how data are stored on disk, the cluster-size),
- your hardware (HDD seek time, or SSD access times),
- the size of your mat file (whether it moves into non-contiguous space),
- and the current state of your storage (existing fragmentation / free space).

Let's pretend that you're running a recent Windows OS, and so are using the [NTFS file-system](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/inside-ntfs). Let's further assume that it has been set up with the default 4 kB cluster size. So, space on disk gets allocated in [4 kB chunks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) and the locations of these are indexed to the Master File Table. If the file grows and contiguous space is not available then there are only two choices:

1. Re-write the entire file to a new part of the disk, where there is sufficient free space.
2. Fragment the file, storing the additional data at a different physical location on disk.

The file system chooses to do the least-bad option, #2, and updates the MFT record to indicate where the new clusters will be on disk.

[image: Illustration of fragmented file on NTFS, from WindowsITPro]

Now, the hard disk needs to physically move the read head in order to read or write the new clusters, and this is a (relatively) slow process. In terms of moving the head, and waiting for the right area of disk to spin underneath it ... you're likely to be looking at a seek time of [about 10ms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#SEEKTIME). So for every time you hit a fragment, there will be an additional 10ms delay whilst the HDD moves to access the new data. SSDs have much shorter seek times (no moving parts). For the sake of simplicity, we're ignoring multi-platter systems and RAID arrays!

If you keep growing the file at different times, then you may experience a lot of fragmentation. This really depends on when / how much the file is growing by, and how else you are using the hard disk. The performance hit that you experience will also depend on how often you are reading the file, and how frequently you encounter the fragments.

MATLAB stores data in [Column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), and from the comments it seems that you're interested in performing column-wise operations (sums, averages) on the dataset. If the columns become non-contiguous on disk then you're going to hit lots of fragments on every operation!

As mentioned in the comments, both read and write actions will be performed via a buffer. As @user3666197 points out the OS can speculatively read-ahead of the current data on disk, on the basis that you're likely to want that data next. This behaviour is especially useful if the hard disk would be sitting idle at times - keeping it operating at maximum capacity and working with small parts of the data in buffer memory can greatly improve read and write performance. However, from your question it sounds as though you want to perform large operations on a huge (too big for memory) .mat file. Given your use-case, the hard disk is going to be working at capacity *anyway*, and the data file is too big to fit in the buffer - so these particular tricks won't solve your problem.

So ...Yes, you *should* pre-allocate. Yes, a performance hit from growing the array on disk will apply. Yes, it will probably be significant (it depends on specifics like amount of growth, fragmentation, etc). And if you're going to *really* get into the HPC spirit of things then stop what you're doing, throw away MATLAB , shard your data and try something like Apache Spark! But that's another story.

Does that answer your question?

P.S. Corrections / amendments welcome! I was brought up on POSIX inodes, so sincere apologies if there are any inaccuracies in here...

Comment: With all due respect, the story approximates **write-through**, non-buffered, dumb HDD-io hardware chain. The read part of the story is missing, where additional conceptual services make the low-level devices perform better than described, due to read-ahead buffering, advanced recalculations of the HDD-physical-head/cylinder/plate geometries into an abstracted, more efficient trajectories with elevator-alike optimisations for the actual read-ordering with smoothed geometry. Additionaly O/S performs an additional layer of read-ahead caching. So the resulting figures on read-side way get better

Comment: +1, very good points about read-ahead buffering and optimised hardware abstractions. As you said, those techniques will help to mitigate the read-side performance hit of fragmentation, but they won't completely fix it - especially since the OP's file is too large to work with in memory so can't be totally buffered. The recommendation for the OP is still going to be "pre-allocate space", right?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The main point, I guess, is that I was wrong in the question to assume that writing in one session avoids fragmentation.

Comment: Fragmentation is a "visible" static detail @ randomIO.As asked -- @SimonW would you,please,add a few **quantitative details important for performance envelope(s)**, that would allow to critically assess available workaround(s) altogether with the (un)-avoid-able overheads associated with 'em? [a] How big is your "large" array in [TB]. [b] How much static / how much varying is the array / sparse-array / size/shape/mapping during the phase of further processing? [c] How intensive is your processing-phase's number-crunching expected / estimated to be -- in [GFLOPs * hrs] –  user3666197 yesterday

Comment: @user3666197 already done. See my recent comment on the question.

Comment: @Simon If your storage medium is clean then writing in one session should minimise fragmentation as the filesystem *will* intelligently try to put the data into contiguous free space. Significant growth of the data is likely to result in additional fragmentation. As you've said, this discussion is starting to morph into a different question ;)

Comment: @GnomeDePlume Yes, topic moved a lot, however, if you take real-system and measure a 1TB write duration, and check the resulting file fragmentation, you would see that the **illusion of contiguous file fails ( even without an incremental extension, that will appear so many times due to MATLAB limitations on both WorkSpace & Array maximum sizes ... so the 1TB will be produced in a one or two orders of magnitude longer time, than a sustained-write ( under a heavy concurrent HDD-IO writes from other parts of the O/S & apps ... )** So, beware, **reality is by far less optimistic on this subject.**

Comment: Hi GnomeDePlume, your answer makes perfect sense, but as I found practically (detailed in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139832/preallocating-a-large-array-in-a-matlab-matfile-with-something-other-than-zeroes/27278859#27278859)), at least the kind of preallocation I tried to do there massively *slows down* the process. Do you have and idea what the difference is here?

Comment: @A.Donda -- nice link, the first time here an HDD.IO time is referred to in the context of the (nonsensical) ***"preallocation"*** for HDF5 fileformat, which in the scales of the OP will consume days... **THANKS FOR SHARING.**

Answer (score 2):

Preallocating a variable in RAM and preallocating on the disk don't solve the same problem.

### In RAM

To expand a matrix in RAM, MATLAB creates a new matrix with the new size and copies the values of the old matrix into the new one and deletes the old one. This costs a lot of performance.

If you preallocated the matrix, the size of it does not change. So there is no more reason for MATLAB to do this matrix copying anymore.

### On the hard-disk

The problem on the hard-disk **is fragmentation** as GnomeDePlume said. Fragmentation will still be a problem, even if the file is written in one session.

Here is why: The hard disk will generally be a little fragmentated. Imagine

- `#` to be memory blocks on the hard disk that are full
- `M` to be memory blocks on the hard disk that will be used to save data of your matrix
- `-` to be free memory blocks on the hard disk

Now the hard disk could look like this before you write the matrix onto it:

```
###--##----#--#---#--------------------##-#---------#---#----#------
```

When you write parts of the matrix (e.g. `MMM` blocks) you could imagine the process to look like this >!(I give an example where the file system will just go from left to right and use the first free space that is big enough - real file systems are different):

1. First matrix part:
   `###--##MMM-#--#---#--------------------##-#---------#---#----#------`
2. Second matrix part:
   `###--##MMM-#--#MMM#--------------------##-#---------#---#----#------`
3. Third matrix part:
   `###--##MMM-#--#MMM#MMM-----------------##-#---------#---#----#------`
4. And so on ...

Clearly the matrix file on the hard disk is fragmented although we wrote it without doing anything else in the meantime.

This can be better if the matrix file was preallocated. In other words, we tell the file system how big our file would be, or in this example, how many memory blocks we want to reserve for it.

Imagine the matrix needed 12 blocks: `MMMMMMMMMMMM`. We tell the file system that we need so much by preallocating and it will try to accomodate our needs as best as it can. In this example, we are lucky: There is free space with >= 12 memory blocks.

1. Preallocating (We need 12 memory blocks):
   `###--##----#--#---# (------------) --------##-#---------#---#----#------`
   The file system reserves the space between the parentheses for our matrix and will write into there.
2. First matrix part:
   `###--##----#--#---# (MMM---------) --------##-#---------#---#----#------`
3. Second matrix part:
   `###--##----#--#---# (MMMMMM------) --------##-#---------#---#----#------`
4. Third matrix part:
   `###--##----#--#---# (MMMMMMMMM---) --------##-#---------#---#----#------`
5. Fourth and last part of the matrix:
   `###--##----#--#---# (MMMMMMMMMMMM) --------##-#---------#---#----#------`

Voilá, no fragmentation!

---

### Analogy

Generally you could imagine this process as buying cinema tickets for a large group. You would like to stick together as a group, but there are already some seats in the theatre reserved by other people. For the cashier to be able to accomodate to your request (large group wants to stick together), he/she needs knowledge about how big your group is (preallocating).

Answer (score 2):

A **quick answer** to the whole discussion (in case you do not have the time to follow or the technical understanding):

- Pre-allocation in Matlab is relevant for operations in RAM. Matlab does not give low-level access to I/O operations and thus we **cannot** talk about pre-allocating something on disk.
- When writing a big amount of data to disk, it has been observed that the fewer the number of writes, the faster is the execution of the task and smaller is the fragmentation on disk.

Thus, if you cannot write in one go, **split the writes in big chunks**.

Answer (score -3):

### Prologue

**This answer is based on both the original post and the clarifications** ( both ) provided by the author during the recent week.

**The question of adverse performance hit**(s) **introduced by** a low-level, physical-media-dependent, **"fragmentation"**, introduced by both a file-system & file-access layers **is further confronted** both in a TimeDOMAIN magnitudes and in ComputingDOMAIN repetitiveness of these **with the real-use problems** of such an approach.

**Finally** a state-of-art, **principally fastest possible solution to the given task was proposed**, so as to minimise damages from both wasted efforts and mis-interpretation errors from idealised or otherwise not valid assumptions, alike that a risk of "serious file fragmentation is low" due to an assumption, that the whole file will be written in one session ( which is simply principally **not possible** during many multi-core / multi-process operations of the contemporary O/S in real-time over a time-of-creation and a sequence of extensive modification(s) ( ref. the MATLAB size limits ) of a TB-sized BLOB file-object(s) inside contemporary COTS FileSystems ).

---

One may hate the facts, however the facts remain true out there until a faster & better method moves in

---

### First, before considering performance, realise the gaps in the concept

1. The real performance adverse hit is ***not* caused** by HDD-IO or related to the file fragmentation
2. RAM is **not an alternative** for the semi-permanent storage of the **`.mat`** file
3. Additional operating system limits and **interventions** + additional driver and hardware-based abstractions were ignored from assumptions on un-avoidable overheads
4. The said computational scheme was omited from the review of what will have the biggest impact / influence on the **resulting performance**

**Given:**

- The whole processing is intended to be **run just once**, no optimisation / iterations, no continuous processing
- Data have **`1E6`** `double` Float-values **x** **`1E5`** columns =  about **`0.8 TB`** (+`HDF5` overhead)
- In spite of original post, there is **no random IO** associated with the processing
- Data **acquisition** phase communicates with a .NET to receive `DataELEMENT`s **into MATLAB**

  That means, since v7.4,

  a **`1.6 GB limit`**  on **MATLAB WorkSpace** in a 32bit Win ( 2.7 GB with a 3GB switch )

  a **`1.1 GB limit`** on **MATLAB biggest Matrix** in wXP / 1.4 GB wV / 1.5 GB

  a bit "released" `2.6 GB limit` on MATLAB WorkSpace + 2.3 GB limit on a biggest Matrix in a 32bit Linux O/S.

  Having a 64bit O/S will not help any kind of a 32bit MATLAB 7.4 implementation and **will fail to work due to another limit**, the maximum number of cells in array, which will not cover the 1E12 requested here.

  The only chance is to have **both**

  - **both** a 64bit O/S ( wXP, Linux, Solaris )
  - **and** a 64bit MATLAB 7.5+

    [MathWorks' source for R2007a cited above, for newer MATLAB R2013a you need a User Account there](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91711-what-is-the-maximum-matrix-size-for-each-platform)
- Data **storage** phase assumes block-writes of a row-ordered data blocks ( a collection of row-ordered data blocks ) into a `MAT-file` on an HDD-device
- Data **processing** phase assumes to re-process the data in a `MAT-file` on an HDD-device, after all inputs have been acquired and marshalled to a file-based off-RAM-storage, but in a column-ordered manner
- just column-wise `mean()`-s / `max()`-es are needed to calculate ( **nothing more complex** )

**Facts:**

- MATLAB uses a "restricted" implementation of an **`HDF5`** file-structure for binary files.

[Review performance measurements on real-data & real-hardware ( HDD + SSD ) to get feeling of scales of the un-avoidable weaknesses thereof](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/improving-save-performance/)

The Hierarchical Data Format (`HDF`) was born on 1987 at the National Center for **Supercomputing** Applications (**NCSA**), some 20 years ago. Yes, that old. The goal was to develop a file format that combine ***flexibility*** and ***efficiency*** to deal with extremely large datasets. Somehow the HDF file was not used in the mainstream as just a few industries were indeed able to really make use of it's **terrifying capacities** or simply did not need them.

*FLEXIBILITY* means that the file-structure bears some overhead, one need not use if the content of the array is not changing ( you **pay the cost** without consuming any benefit of using it ) and an assumption, that `HDF5` limits on overall size of the data it can contain sort of helps and saves the MATLAB side of the problem is not correct.

`MAT-files` are good in principle, as they avoid an otherwise persistent need to load a whole file into RAM to be able to work with it.

Nevertheless, `MAT-files` are not serving well the simple task as was defined and clarified here. An attempt to do that will result in just a poor performance and HDD-IO file-fragmentation ( adding a few tens of milliseconds during **`write-through`**-s and something less than that on **`read-ahead`**-s during the calculations ) will not help at all in judging the core-reason for the overall poor performance.

---

### A professional solution approach

Rather than moving the whole gigantic set of **`1E12`** `DataELEMENT`s into a MATLAB in-memory proxy data array, that is just scheduled for a next coming sequenced stream of `HDF5` / `MAT-file` HDD-device IO-s ( `write-through`s and O/S vs. hardware-device-chain conflicting/sub-optimised `read-ahead`s ) so as to have all the immenses work "just [married] ready" for a few & trivially simple calls of **`mean()`** / **`max()`** MATLAB functions( that will do their best to revamp each of the **`1E12`** `DataELEMENT`s in just another order ( and **even TWICE -- yes --** another circus right after the first job-processing nightmare gets all the way down, **through all the HDD-IO bottlenecks** ) back into MATLAB in-RAM-objects, **do redesign** this very step **into a pipe-line BigDATA processing from the very beginning.**

```
while true                                          % ref. comment Simon W Oct 1 at 11:29
   [ isStillProcessingDotNET,   ...                 %      a FLAG from .NET reader function
     aDotNET_RowOfVALUEs ...                        %      a ROW  from .NET reader function
     ] = GetDataFromDotNET( aDtPT )                 %                  .NET reader
   if ( isStillProcessingDotNET )                   % Yes, more rows are still to come ...
      aRowCOUNT = aRowCOUNT + 1;                    %      keep .INC for aRowCOUNT ( mean() )
      for i = 1:size( aDotNET_RowOfVALUEs )(2)      %      stepping across each column
         aValue     = aDotNET_RowOfVALUEs(i);       %      
         anIncrementalSumInCOLUMN(i) = ...
         anIncrementalSumInCOLUMN(i) + aValue;      %      keep .SUM for each column ( mean() )
         if ( aMaxInCOLUMN(i) < aValue )            %      retest for a "max.update()"
              aMaxInCOLUMN(i) = aValue;             %      .STO a just found "new" max
         end
      endfor
      continue                                      %      force re-loop
   else
      break
   endif
end
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% FINALLY:
% all results are pre-calculated right at the end of .NET reading phase:
%
% -------------------------------
% BILL OF ALL COMPUTATIONAL COSTS ( for given scales of 1E5 columns x 1E6 rows ):
% -------------------------------
% HDD.IO:          **ZERO**
% IN-RAM STORAGE:
%                  Attr Name                       Size                     Bytes  Class
%                  ==== ====                       ====                     =====  =====
%                       aMaxInCOLUMNs              1x100000                800000  double
%                       anIncrementalSumInCOLUMNs  1x100000                800000  double
%                       aRowCOUNT                  1x1                          8  double
%
% DATA PROCESSING:
%
% 1.000.000x .NET row-oriented reads ( same for both the OP and this, smarter BigDATA approach )
%         1x   INT   in aRowCOUNT,                 %%       1E6 .INC-s
%   100.000x FLOATs  in aMaxInCOLUMN[]             %% 1E5 * 1E6 .CMP-s
%   100.000x FLOATs  in anIncrementalSumInCOLUMN[] %% 1E5 * 1E6 .ADD-s
% -----------------
% about 15 sec per COLUMN of 1E6 rows
% -----------------
%                  --> mean()s are anIncrementalSumInCOLUMN./aRowCOUNT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PIPE-LINE-d processing takes in TimeDOMAIN "nothing" more than the .NET-reader process
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Your **pipe-line**d BigDATA computation strategy will in a smart way **principally avoid** interim storage buffering in MATLAB as it will progressively calculate the results in not more than about **`3 x 1E6`** ADD/CMP-registers, all with a static layout, **avoid** proxy-storage into `HDF5` / `MAT-file`, **absolutely avoid** all HDD-IO related bottlenecks and low BigDATA sustained-read-s' speeds ( not speaking at all about interim/BigDATA sustained-writes... ) and will **also avoid** ill-performing memory-mapped use just for counting mean-s and max-es.

---

### Epilogue

The pipeline processing is nothing new under the Sun.

It re-uses what **speed-oriented HPC solutions** already use for decades

[ generations before BigDATA tag has been "invented" in Marketing Dept's. ]

Forget about zillions of HDD-IO blocking operations & go into a pipelined distributed process-to-process solution.

---

### There is nothing faster than this

---

**If it were**, all FX business and HFT Hedge Fund Monsters would already be there...

Comment: While a lot of effort seems to have gone into this tirade, it does not answer the question. Rather, it addresses the example given in order to say "you're doing it wrong".

Comment: **Yes** Simon, exactly. **Improving "ill-directed" efforts does not help you achieving your general and respected goal**, to get the data processed in a reasonable time.

Comment: I did not ask anybody to solve my problem (about which you have made a lot of assumptions). I asked a simple question about best practice, which might be relevant to myself or others in the future. You have ignored the question that I asked.

Comment: Negative, Simon, **having asked you to clarify & quantitatively specify all relevant details and you have provided such facts & numbers, that were later used in a fair manner** for all derived implications in the respose, it can not be serious to say someone "ignored" your question. If your goal is other, than you have explained, as it might sound from your objection in your comment 1 min ago, why didn't you explain the very real use / the very real problem of the issue?

Comment: This particular calculation was nearly two months ago and is now entirely moot. I agree that, given the limited information here, the method given would not be the optimum approach. That's beside the point. The question is about general best practice: "Given that I am doing A, should I do B?". You have answered "You shouldn't do A". That is unhelpful.

Comment: With all due respect, Simon, the **criticism** does not aim in a correct direction. **"Given that you have said, you are doing [A], you should not do [B] (under no circumstances) & you better do [A] faster in a way proposed, in a pipe-lined mode of calculation, as all other methods are many orders of magnitude slower,** cause lengthy blocking periods of sustained write-s & read-s (the latter even repeated twice(!!), which in O(1) system is not a responsible practice in case you can have results in O(0) time right at the end of DataELEMENTs acquisition phase(!!!)". **Just measure a 1TB write**

Comment: Previous, somewhat sweary response, deleted. Let's just say that I won't be replying here any more, and that you don't do anything for the reputation of Stackoverflow.